# Django form won't show up on template

Tags: python, django

I'm making a sign in system in Django Python, i've been preparing the forms.py, views.py and the template itself, but so far the form fail to load on the template, can anyone help?

Forms.py

```
class Email_Only_SignUp_Form(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(initial='Your Email...')
```

Views.py

```
def email_only_signup_form(request, template_name):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        signup_form = Email_Only_SignUp_Form(request.POST)

        if signup_form.is_valid():
            email = signup_form.cleaned_data['email']
            username = email

            try:
                #check for duplicate username
                    User.objects.get(username=username)
                    email_error = 'email already exist'
            except:
                #initial creation of user object
                try:
                    import os, random, string

                    length = 13
                    chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!@$()'
                    random.seed = (os.urandom(1024))
                    password = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(length))

                    User.objects.create_user(username,
                                             username,
                                             password,
                    )
                    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
                    user_profile=UserProfile(user=user)
                    user_profile.save()

                    #send email to user
                    try:
                        admin_email = settings.EMAIL_ORIGIN_MEMBERS
                        email_txt = loader.get_template('account/emails/createaccount.html')
                        email_html = loader.get_template('account/emails/createaccounthtml.html')
                        email_context = Context({'u_name': username,
                                                 'username': username,
                                                 'password': password,
                                                })
                        new_user_mail = EmailMultiAlternatives('Welcome!',
                                                               email_txt.render(email_context),
                                                               admin_email,
                                                               [user.email, ],
                                                               headers={'Reply-To': 'admin@admin.com'}
                        )
                        new_user_mail.attach_alternative(email_html.render(email_context), 'text/html')
                        new_user_mail.send()
                    except:
                        pass

                    return redirect('/account/thankyou/?next=%s'%next)

                except:
                     pass

        else:
            print('user form in not valid')

    else:
        signup_form = Email_Only_SignUp_Form()

    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

email_only_signup_form.html

```
{% extends "index.html" %}

{% block heroslider %}
    <div class="page_title2" style="padding:150px 0px 50px 0px;">
        <div class="container">

            <h1>User Registration</h1>

        </div>
    </div><!-- end page title -->
{% endblock %}

{% block main_body %}

<style type="text/css">
    input[type='radio'], input[type='checkbox'] {
        width:20px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    div.reg_error {
        position:relative;
        top:-10px;
        margin-top:0px;
        padding-top:0px;
        color:red;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <form class="pagesignup logiform" action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                <div class="reg_form">
                    <div class="sky-form">
                        <header>REGISTER</header>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="large-12 columns">

                            <p>Email<br/>
                                {{signup_form.email}}
                            <div class="reg_error">{{ signup_form.email.errors.as_text }}{{email_error}}</div></p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="large-12 large-centered columns" style="text-align:center;padding:20px;">
                            <input class="but_medium1" style="border:none;" type = "submit" value="REGISTER" /><br>
                            <br>By clicking on register, you have read and agreed to our <a href="/terms-of-use/">terms of use</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<!-- Google Code for Sign Up Page (landed) Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var google_conversion_id = 969557266;
    var google_conversion_language = "en";
    var google_conversion_format = "3";
    var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
    var google_conversion_label = "5zU4CJby_FoQkoqpzgM";
    var google_remarketing_only = false;
    /* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
    <div style="display:inline;">
    <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/969557266/?label=5zU4CJby_FoQkoqpzgM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
    </div>
</noscript>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: "Here's 140 lines of code. It doesn't work. Can anyone help?" What is happening? Can you give us some error message text, or examples of how you have tried to debug this?

Comment: Passing in `locals()` to the template? Seriously?

Comment: Argh. Remove all those `except: pass` lines. Exceptions happen for a reason; catching them *and then disposing them* is bound to lead to disaster.

Answer (score 2):

You have not passed the signup_form to the template.

```
return render_to_response(template_name,  {'signup_form': signup_form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I have no idea what locals() does.

Edit: I just saw locals which is a built in python function. It will be better if you explicitly pass the variables you need in the template.

Edit 2:  Check if it is the correct template_name. In the template simply print and see the form {{ signup_form }}. See if it is available.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning the form. 
Try changing the last line of the view to

```
return render_to_response(template_name, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request, {'signup_form' : signup_form ))
```